# Using left over pickle juice to make more pickles

Tags: flavor

Can the juice from store bought dill pickles be used to make more pickles.  Can fresh cucumbers put into this juice aquire the same flavor as buying more pickles. If so how long would the cucumbers have to be in the 'juice' for full flavor?

Comment: I'm not sure how different the question would be with store bought vs. home made, but see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/23539/67

Answer (score 1):

I tried it once. They just spoiled in a few days. I think you need to go through the whole pickle-making process rather than just adding cucumbers to a jar of brine. There's a sterilization that you're not getting, I think.

I have seen recipes and pre-packaged "refrigerator pickle" mixes, ("Mrs." somebody... comes to mind) but haven't made any. I've eaten them, and they were pretty tasty.